# reduction for sum of vector when size is not power of 2?

Tags: cuda

For the classical reduction algorithm on GPU, it works perfectly if the size of vector is the power of 2. What if it is not the case? At some point we will have to find the sum of odd number of element. What is the best way to deal with that?

Comment: a simple if phrase would solve the problem. just take the ceiling of the half and check if the current thread is eligible for reduction.

Comment: Have you considered using an `if` statement ?

Comment: Sum of vector values on GPU is likely useless because of the bottleneck of transferring data to the GPU: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194798/vector-step-addition-slower-on-cuda You need more computational intensity per bytes (e.g. matrix multiplication) to see any speedup.

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功 That's true, but if the data is already on GPU, it's probably better than copying back to CPU and doing the sum on CPU, no ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compute the sum of a matrix that doesn't have a size of a power of two. Look at the example :

```
#include <math.h>
#define N 1022 //total size
__global__ void sum(int *A, int *C)
{
        __shared__ int temp[blockDim.x];
        int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
        int local_idx = threadIdx.x;
        temp[local_idx] = A[idx];
        int i=ceil(blockDim.x/2);
        __syncthreads();
        while(i!=0)
        {
                 if(idx+i<N && local_idx<i)
                          temp[local_idx] += tmp[local_idx+i];
                 i/=2;
                 __syncthreads();

        }
       if(local_idx == 0)
           C[blockIdx.x] = temp[0]; 
}
```

Comment: It looks to me your answer is not doing what  you mentioned in the comment. (take ceiling of the half). But I got your idea.

Comment: @szli I've fixed it to reflect what I've said in the comment.

Comment: I think there are a couple typos here, for anyone who may be trying to compile this. Shouldn't there be an extern keyword before the __shared__ declaration? Also "tmp" should be read "temp."

Comment: This code doesn't work. Can you please correct small details mentioned by @millw and also explain about: int i=ceil(blockDim.x/2); Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set

`int i = 1024;`

instead of

`int i=ceil(blockDim.x/2);`

i.e. int i should be interger^2 > N.

Comment: Mistake!  int i = 512. i.e. int i should be (interger^2 > N) / 2.