# how to add up the elements of an array in GPU? any function similar to cublasDasum in CUBLAS?

Tags: arrays, cuda, gpu, addition, reduction

I know I can do the [parallel reduction](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) to sum up the elements of an array in parallel.
But it is a little difficult for me to follow it. I saw that in cublas, there is this function called `cublasDasum` that sums up the absolute values of the elements. It seems there should be a very similar function that sums up the elements, not the absolute values. Is there any way I can find the source code of `cublasDasum` and see how this is done?

Adding up an array is such a basic operation. I can't believe that there is no such a function that does it ... .

Comment: Sum of vector values on GPU is likely useless because of the bottleneck of transferring data to the GPU: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194798/vector-step-addition-slower-on-cuda You need more computational intensity per bytes (e.g. matrix multiplication) to see any speedup.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862078/cuda-code-for-sum-of-rows-of-a-matrix-too-slow) for some good ideas.  [Thrust](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html) has pretty easy to use reduction operations.

You can sum all the elements of a matrix by treating it as a 1 x N array, creating an N x 1 array of ones, and doing a `cublasDgemm` operation.

I don't think you're going to find the source code for cublas anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can use cublasDaxpy ( AXPY blas equivalent) with alpha = 1 which performs:

y = alpha.x  + y

And if you work on matrix, you can use cublasDgeam ( no BLAS equivalent )

Comment: axpy takes two vectors and produces a vector result.  The OP wants to take a single vector (matrix) and produce a scalar result.