# Reduction of odd number of elements CUDA

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu, reduction

It seems that it possible to make reduction only for odd number of elements. For example, it needs to sum up numbers. When I have even number of elements, it will be like this:

```
1 2 3 4
1+2
3+3
6+4
```

But what to do when I have, for instance `1 2 3 4 5`? The last iteration is the sum of three elements 6+4+5 or what? I saw the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161575/reduction-for-sum-of-vector-when-size-is-not-power-of-2), but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A parallel reduction will add pairs of elements first:

```
1  1+3   4+6
2  2+4
3
4
```

Your example with an odd number of elements would typically be realized as:

```
1  1+4  5+3  8+7
2  2+5  7+0
3  3+0
4  0+0
5
0
0
0
```

That is to say, typically a parallel reduction will work with a power-of-2 set of threads, and at most one threadblock (the last one) will have less than a full complement of data to work with.  The usual method to handle this is to zero-pad the data out to the threadblock size.  If you study the cuda [parallel reduction](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) sample code, you'll find examples of this.

Comment: Zero-padding is a very bad idea, think about multiplication instead of addition. More generally, it requires us to know a neutral element of the reduction operation. The latter can be anything, sum, multiply, min, max, ... I think the only proper solution is with an if-clause.